# How to replicate a CSS3 animated button?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to replicate a CSS3 animated button from a website I am on. I have got most of the styling working, besides the actual animation itself.

[Here is the button.](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/) I am trying to do the star, that is third section form the bottom with the green background. Capture is below.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<button id="BUTTON_1">
    Fav
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
#BUTTON_1 {
    box-shadow: rgb(17, 158, 77) 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 60px;
    perspective-origin: 30px 25px;
    transform-origin: 30px 25px;
    background: rgb(23, 170, 86) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    font: normal normal bold 0px/normal Lato, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 25px 30px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

 #BUTTON_1:after {
    color: rgb(255, 228, 77);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    speak: none;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-self: flex-start;
    perspective-origin: 30px 25px;
    transform: matrix(4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0);
    transform-origin: 30px 25px;
    content:'';
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 228, 77);
    font: normal normal normal 26px/54px icomoon;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(255, 228, 77) none 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
}

 #BUTTON_1:before {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    speak: none;
    top: 0px;
    width: 60px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-self: flex-start;
    perspective-origin: 30px 25px;
    transform-origin: 30px 25px;
    content:'';
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal 26px/54px icomoon;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

 .#BUTTON_1:before {
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
}

.#BUTTON_1:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 54px;
    color: #ffe44d;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #ffe44d;
    -webkit-transform: scale(4);
    -moz-transform: scale(4);
    -ms-transform: scale(4);
    transform: scale(4);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

.#BUTTON_1.btn-activated:after {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: dropDown 0.3s forwards;
    -moz-animation: dropDown 0.3s forwards;
    animation: dropDown 0.3s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dropDown {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes dropDown {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes dropDown {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

[**Demo of my attempt**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpzy424o/1)

Not worried about the font (as you can see, my example does not have the font installed), just after the animation working on the button. I have tried finding all the keyframes and styles that are attached, but I still cannot seem to get it working.

What am I missing to get this working?

Comment: you want to repeat the button or the button star is not working?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv - I want to replicate the button exactly (click animation, colours, everything besides the font). The site it is currently on is not mine, so I am trying to replicate it EXACTLY onto my site.

Comment: post my answer can u chk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class="btn-activated" is missing in <button id="BUTTON_1" class="btn-activated">
```

And remove dot,

```
.#BUTTON_1.btn-activated:after {
( In all cases .#BUTTON_1)
```

to

```
#BUTTON_1.btn-activated:after {
```

jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#BUTTON_1').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('btn-activated');
    });     
});
</script>
```

In your fiddle select jquery in Frameworks & Extensions

And In javascipt bar

Paste it

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#BUTTON_1').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('btn-activated');
    });     
});
```

And,

```
<button id="BUTTON_1" class="btn-activated">
```

to

```
<button id="BUTTON_1">
```

Comment: No luck. Updated fiddle here still does not work - http://jsfiddle.net/Lpzy424o/8/

Comment: u dint remove dot .#BUTTON_1:after {,.#BUTTON_1.btn-activated:after {

Comment: Works well. But it only runs on load, not on click. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, they are using jquery for that. Is there any issue using jQuery from your end?